# Having trouble setting up enviorment variable MEAN stack .zshrc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, zshrc, filepicker

I am using ZSH and my the environment variable is this:

```
FILEPICKER='xxxxxxxxxxx'
export FILEPICKER
```

I know that the `.zshrc` is set up properly because have had access to my environment variables in previous projects.

I am having trouble figuring out how to access this in my MEAN app.

This is my `app.js` file that is throwing the error:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['addCarCtrl', 'galleryCtrl','detailCtrl','userCtrl', 'ngRoute', 'angular-filepicker'])

app.config(function($routeProvider, filepickerProvider){
    //The route provider handles the client request to switch route
    $routeProvider.when('/addCar', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/addCar.html',
        controller: 'addCarController'
    })
    .when('/gallery', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html',
        controller: 'galleryController'
    })
    .when('/detail/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: 'detailController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'userController'
    })
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    })

    filepickerProvider.setKey(FILEPICKER);

});
```

Do I need a `process.env` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my problem is that you cannot access environment variables from the front end and I was calling them correctly with process.env.ENV_VAR

This link what I used to get around this issue:

https://medium.com/@kudresov/a-better-way-to-inject-environmental-variables-in-angular-d3b2d01a3c5e#.wrv2sc17g